# extract specific text from image

Tags: python, node.js, image-processing, text

I'm trying to extract specific (or the whole text and then parse it) text from the image.
the image is in the **Hebrew** language.
what I already tried in nodejs is using in [Tesseract](https://github.com/naptha/tesseract.js?files=1) library but in Hebrew, it does not recognize the text good.
I'm also tried to convert the image to pdf and then parse from pdf but it's not working well in Hebrew.
anyone has already tried to do that? maybe with python or node js?
I'm trying to do something like cloud vision google text

Comment: what library did you use in Python to convert the image to pdf? might recommend to use _PyMuPDF_ but not sure if the package recognizes Hebrew

Comment: in python I didn't try. in nodejs is pdf-parser

Comment: These two links [https://github.com/pymupdf/PyMuPDF/issues/398][https://github.com/pymupdf/PyMuPDF/issues/409] might be useful for you. Based on the open issues on git, _PyMuPDF_ might not supportive for Hebrew but _polyglot_ does

Comment: the second link not works

Comment: https://github.com/pymupdf/PyMuPDF/issues/398 this is the first one; https://github.com/pymupdf/PyMuPDF/issues/409 this is the second link.

Comment: how does it helps me? I'm looking for library to extract text from images or pdf

Comment: _PyMuPDF_ or _polyglot_ might be your option then

Comment: Polyglot is a natural language pipeline that supports massive multilingual applications.
I don't think it's for extract data from pdf\image. can you show example please?

Comment: Did you had any luck with that? @Manspof

Answer (score 0):

have you tried preprocessing the image you feed to tesseract? In case you didn't I would give a try to use OpenCV contour detection, particularly Hough Line Transform, and then clean it up a bit. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lhMXDqQHf9g&list=PLQVvvaa0QuDeETZEOy4VdocT7TOjfSA8a&index=5 this guy doesn't do your stuff exactly, but if ya take time to scroll bit you can see how it can be useful.

Comment: yes I tried with tesseract but it doesn't work well with hebrew

Answer (score 0):

Based on our conversation in OP. Here is some options for you to consider.

**Option 1:**

If you are working directly with PDFs as your input file

```
import fitz
input_file = '/path/to/your/pdfs/'
pdf_file = input_file

doc = fitz.open(pdf_file)
noOfPages = doc.pageCount

for pageNo in range(noOfPages):
    page = doc.loadPage(pageNo) 
    pageTextblocks = page.getText('blocks') # This creates a list of items (x0,y0,x1,y1,"line1\nline2\nline3...",...)
    pageTextblocks.sort(key=lambda block: block[3]) 
    for block in pageTextblocks:
        targetBlock = block[4] # This gets to the content of each block and you can work your logic here to get relevant data
```

**Option 2:**

If you are working with image as your input and you need to convert it to PDFs before processing it using code snippet in Option 1.

```
doc = fitz.open(input_file)
pdfbytes = doc.convertToPDF() # open it as a pdf file
pdf = fitz.open("pdf", pdfbytes) # extract data as a pdf file
```

One useful tip for processing image in PyMuPDF is to use `zoom` factor for better resolution if the image is somewhat hard to be recognized.

```
zoom = 1.2 # scale the image by 120%
mat = fitz.Matrix(zoom,zoom)
```

**Option 3:**

A hybrid approach with PyMuPDF and pytesseract since you've mentioned tesseract. I am not sure if this approach fits your needs to extract Hebrew language but it's an idea. The example is used for PDFs.

```
import fitz
import pytesseract

pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r'/path/to/your/tesseract/cmd'
input_file = '/path/to/pdfs'

pdf_file = input_file
fullText = ""

doc = fitz.open(pdf_file)
zoom = 1.2
mat = fitz.Matrix(zoom, zoom)
noOfPages = doc.pageCount

for pageNo in range(noOfPages):
    page = doc.loadPage(pageNo) #number of page
    pix = page.getPixmap(matrix = mat)
    output = '/path/to/save/image' + str(pageNo) + '.jpg'
    pix.writePNG(output)
    print('Converting PDFs to Image ... ' + output)
    text_of_each_page = str(((pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open(output)))))
    
    fullText += text_without_whitespace

    fullText += '\n'
```

Hope this helps. If you need more information about PyMuPDF, [click this link](https://pymupdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq/) and it has a more detailed explanation to fit your needs.

Comment: can you explain how to use your option 2? because it does not work for me

Comment: @LidorEliyahuShelef i think the option 3 is a combination of both 1 and 2, which should be working on my case. Not sure if it works on Hebrew but feel free to give it a try.